# Why is a Jewish slave called an Eved Ivri and not Eved Israeli?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mishpatim

Why throughout Judaism (starting from [Parashat Mishpotim - Shemos 21:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0221.htm) a Jewish slave is called Eved Ivri כִּי תִקְנֶה עֶבֶד עִבְרִי?

Why does it not call him an Eved Yisroeli, instead? The last mentioning of this term was before the Exodus ("אלקי העברים שלחני") and after Exodus the Jews are called exclusively Bney Isroel.

Comment: Why should he be called an Eved Yisroel?

Comment: The Pasuk calls him that. Where does the Pasuk call a Jew a Yisrael?

Comment: You could improve this question by citing where the phrase "Eved Ivri" comes up and explaining why you feel that a different term would make more sense.

Comment: @GershonGold, I believe that neither "Eretz Yisroel" nor "Klal Yisroel" are found in the Torah.

Comment: @GershonGold Because maybe that was the regular way of referring to Jews back then

Comment: Counterexample to what I said above: Vayikra 24:10 ויצא בן אשה ישראלית והוא בן איש מצרי בתוך בני ישראל וינצו במחנה בן הישראלית ואיש הישראלי: Though that is the only counterexample in Tanach I think.

Comment: @GershonGold, if your question is actually about these latter-day terms, then you should phrase it as such, cite where those terms are seen, and explain why you think they're inconsistent with prior vocabulary.

Comment: @GershonGold I already did provide proof. The pasuk.

Comment: It seems like your question is: why doesn't the pasuk use rabbinic terminology?

Comment: @GershonGold, there's no real question yet to answer.

Comment: Well, first of all, 'Eved Yisrael would be "slave of an Israelite", not an "Israelite slave". Second, what is the motivation behind this question?

Comment: @SethJ lol!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @GershonGold, thanks for the clarification. And I agree with your last point.

Comment: @GershonGold Questions about erections, time zones, lulavs, brachot, money, technology can all have more upvotes if they are phrased as good questions for our format, which is not every question ever. An exact formulation of what kinds of questions are ideal is still being worked out on MSO ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/166155)), but questions are generally expected to include motivation for asking. Since this was intended as a self-answer, see [this post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/307/759) for more about the potential pitfalls of such questions.

Comment: GershonGold, IMHO, the question could use some improvement. While questions about difficult or strange wording in a Pasuk are legitimate, if the answer is just, "Look it up," I'm not sure that's better than, "Here's a Wikipedia article." You could have just looked it up first and had your answer. Ohr HaChaim is not obscure. If he were, I'd say "Oh, good find!" But this whole thing just reads like an awkward set-up, as @DoubleAA indicated in his comment on your answer.

Comment: Also, note that your answer was downvoted before your edits, when it was very unclear what you meant. Perhaps the downvoter has yet to return and change his vote.

Comment: Just a thought...alliteration?

Comment: @DoubleAA, what's being worked out on MSO is the precise wording that all SE sites across the system should have in their boilerplate FAQs to communicate something that has always been the case: **It's up to the question to convince readers that it's a worthwhile question.**

Comment: @GershonGold, It's the question's job to convince the reader that it's a worthwhile question, not answers'. This question has received numerous comments explaining specifically what it's missing and expressing specific skepticism about it premises. Instead of looking for an answer, I recommend that you review these comments and attempt to address them *in the question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See אמת ליעקב by Rabbi Yaakov Kamenetsky who explains that this has to do with the teachings Yeshiva of Ever (Eber) whose students were unaffiliated by family or origin, only by their actions and beliefs, like a slave who is unaffiliated in his low stature. The term Yisroel denotes an exalted person and all people who bear that name are related by affiliation to the Jewish people. I'm not doing his words justice, see it inside...

Answer (score 1):

[Ohr HaChaim HaKodosh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=336) explains that since the word Ivri is from the root עבר meaning 'to pass', and a Eved Ivri only remains an Eved for 6 years, therefore he is called Eved Ivri.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1081/759

Comment: If you accept your  own answer on this, I think @DoubleAA might lose it. Could be fun to watch. ;-)

Comment: @SethJ Me or the three others who upvoted my above comment? The answer isn't bad, it's more the question that's the problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA, i was one of the 3.

Answer (score 1):

Around the time of the Exodus, the Jewish people were known as "Hebrews", certainly as individuals. (Take a look at some Ellis Island records and you'll see a lot of people listing their nationality as "Hebrew, Polish"). As a whole they become known as "Bnai Yisrael." Similarly, Joseph is described as a Hebrew, and Jonah introduces himself as such as well.

It's several hundred years later, when the southern kingdom of Judea is the remaining one, that individual Jews become known as "Yehudim", technically "Judeans." Thus Mordechai in the Megillah is a "Yehudi", generic for "Jew" (as we say in English today, "Juda-ism"), though his actual tribe of ancestry was Benjamin.

The term "Yisrael" to refer to an individual Jew -- "he is a Yisrael" -- much later,  Talmudic terminology.

Comment: See though [Vayikra 24:10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%99)

Comment: Hmmm perhaps also Shmuel II 17:25

Comment: Also, Shifrah and Puah are the "מילדות העבריות". (Shemos 1:15)